# Wrong one-time-password generated by cryptography.hazmat.primitives.twofactor.totp

Tags: python, cryptography, two-factor-authentication

SOLVED:

Using code snippet from he PyOTP library to pad and encode the key before passing it to the algorithm.

```
        missing_padding = len(key) % 8
        if missing_padding != 0:
            key += '=' * (8 - missing_padding)
        byte_key = b32decode(key, casefold=True)
        totp = cryptography.hazmat.primitives.twofactor.totp.TOTP(
            byte_key,
            6,
            SHA1(),
            30,
            backend=default_backend(),
            enforce_key_length=False
        )
        print("{:<10} {}".format(account, totp.generate(time()).decode()))
```

I'm generating one-time passwords for 2-factor authentication using the cryptography and PyOTP libraries.  However, the TOTP objects from the two libraries give different outputs despite using the same key.  I suspect it's something to do whether the key should be provided as a string or bytes-like object, but I'm unsure about how to handle the encoding/decoding.

Snippet (key is provided as a string read from a (encrypted) file) ->

```
        totp = cryptography.hazmat.primitives.twofactor.totp.TOTP(
            key.encode(),
            6,
            SHA1(),
            30,
            backend=default_backend()
        )
        totp2 = pyotp.TOTP(key)
        print("{:<10} {}".format(
            account,
            totp.generate(time()).decode()),
            totp2.now()
        )
```

Result ->

```
Dropbox    508629 405771
```

The OTP generated by PyOTP is consistent with Google Authenticator.

Comment: This is the same generator algo. You're probably not using it properly - different libraries can be very different. Please post the PyOTP code as well.

Comment: I just saw this and don't have time to write a full answer, but Google authenticator needs the key in base32 format, so one or other of those options is likely translating the key for you and the other isn't. I'd look into that.

Comment: Thanks @philnash, that helped.  I managed to fix this by looking into the PyOTP implementation, and noting that it included some padding and encoding of the key before passing it to the algorithm.  Passing this to the cryptography TOTP object solved the problem.

Comment: Awesome, glad that the hint helped! :)